# Javascript wrong binding: function disappear but variables ok

Tags: javascript, requirejs

The problem is that when I am binding `this` to function in `.then()` of `Promise` all variables is binded but 1 which is function, not.

```
define([
'Service/service',
'core/widget'], function (service, widget) {
return widget.extend({
    init: function (options) {
        this.options = options;
        console.log('this.options: ', this.options); //{actionToDo:function(),variables...}

        service.getFile('app/Core/Widgets/Button/Views/button.html')
            .then(
                function(){
                console.log('this.options: ', this.options); //{actionToDo:undefined,...}
                }.bind(this)
            )
    }
});});
```

I am creating the object by:

```
new Button(
                {
                    elementToAppend: this.className + ' .actions > .actionButtons',
                    class: action.class,
                    icon: action.icon,
                    text: action.text,
                    unique: action.unique,
                    actionToDo: function(){//some code}
                }
            );
```

And the `widget`:

```
define(['underscore'], function (_) {

function Widget() {
}

return {
    extend: function (methods) {
        var widget = new Widget();
        widget.prototype = {
            trigger: function (event) {
                switch (event) {
                    case 'click':
                    {
                        this.onClick.call(this);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        var Widget_Extended = _.extend(widget.prototype, methods);
        return function (options) {
            Widget_Extended.init(options);
            return Widget_Extended;
        };
    }
};});
```

Could you tell me why inside function in `.then()` 1 parametr of options is `undefined`?

Answer (score 0):

The solve of the problem (I guess) is:

```
define(['underscore'], function (_) {

function Widget() {
}

return {
    extend: function (methods) {
        return function (options) {
            var widget = new function () {
            };
            widget.prototype = {
                trigger: function (event) {
                    switch (event) {
                        case 'click':
                        {
                            this.onClick.call(this);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            var Widget_Extended = _.extend(widget.prototype, methods);
            Widget_Extended.init(options);
            return Widget_Extended;
        };
    }
};});
```